# How to use r.patch with two maps having different colortables?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, colortable

I am using r.patch to combine two raster maps in order to fill in the null values of the other. Is there a way to use r.patch but still maintaining the colortables of the separate raster maps? I do not want to change the colortable of input1 raster map A and input2 raster map B.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible if the color table of the adjacent raster maps do not overlap. I don't know if r.patch maintains them but you could reassign the colors of the merged color tables after the patching (mosaicking). If there are no identical colors between the maps then the assignment (r.colors) should be successful.

Comment: I tired making the colors of the two maps different (with no identical colors). But still it did not display properly. The r.patch maintains the colortable of the 1st map in input

Comment: Perhaps try i.image.mosaic (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/i.image.mosaic.html)?

Comment: I tried it but the result file could not be displayed in the map display. How can the .mosaic file be displayed?

Comment: Was there an error message? The result is like any other raster map...

Comment: I used the `r.info` function to see the details of the generated map. I saw that there is an additional value of 255 for the cells when I used i.image.mosaic that is why the values were altered. I'm fixing it now. Thanks